# It is possible to generate a JSON schema for dynamic attributes

Tags: json, jsonschema

The problem is that in my app we have a data structure like this:

```
{
  "adults": {
      "jagger_mick_dateOfBirth": {
           "name": "Mick"
           "lastName": "Jagger",
           "more atributes": ""
      },
      "jolie_angelina_dateOfBirth": : {
           "name": "Angelina"
           "lastName": "Jolie",
           "more atributes": ""
      }
  },
  "children": {
      "osbourne_ozzy_dateOfBirth": : {
           "name": "Ozzy"
           "lastName": "Osbourne",
           "more atributes": ""
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, for each Adult & Children, we use a dynamic attribute to identify each object. **BUT inside is the same object**.

Right now I am in the process to generate JSON Schemas (v4) for this data structure.

My problem is i cannot find a property to evaluate dynamic attributes, althought the object is the same, just the key is different.

I know that it is bad coding, but it is possible to generate a JSON Schema (v4) to validate a dynamic attribute (key) ?

Thanks in advance.

P.D.
If you are wondering why we use this approach, is because we can access directly to the object, instead of search for it.

Comment: It is possible, an explanation of how it can be done in JSON Schema v4 can be found [here](http://json-schema.org/example2.html).

Comment: Thanks Patrik. But I don't see in the example how I can configure a dynamic key. To be more precise:

"jagger_mick_dateOfBirth", "jolie_angelina_dateOfBirth" or "osbourne_ozzy_dateOfBirth" are dynamic. Can be whatever name with whateber number of characters.

I hope i better explained myself this time.

Answer (score 0):

If your dynamic object attributes can be described with a regular expression, you can use [patternProperties keyword](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor64).